# Subtract datetimes in different timezones

Tags: datetime, timezone, informix, timezone-offset

I was asked to create a query to pull a near-real-time report from an Informix database (I have select access only, I cannot create a SP) and I felt like I succeeded pretty well until I realized that there was a discrepancy in a datetime field.  it seems that the program that is populating the db is hard-coded to enter the time in the datetime field in UTC (five hours off of the local time.  When the time was 2:30 it entered a row in the database saying John Doe completed the task at 7:30).  In my report I am supposed to calculate the number of seconds (as an int) since the user completed the task (field is "completionTime") and I was originally just using:

```
sysdate - completionTime interval seconds(9) to seconds cast to char then cast to int
```

When I realized the mistake in the timezone of the completionTime field I just subtracted the offset as an integer (I was already converting the interval to an integer, so I just adjusted the answer by 18000).  This worked just fine until Daylight Saving started.  Then all of a sudden local time was 4 hours (14400 seconds instead of 18000) off of UTC.

Since I can only select from the db, I next tried using an inefficient case statement (my query went from <0.5 seconds to 3-5 seconds for only 25 rows).  Following a suggestion from another forum I changed the time to an integer of seconds from the unix epoch, then used the dbinfo('utc_to_datetime') sp to convert it back to a datetime in the right timezone.

This approach works, but the calculation looks terrible to me:

```
cast(cast(cast((sysdate - dbinfo("utc_to_datetime", cast(cast(cast((completionTime - TO_DATE('Friday January 1, 2010 0:00', '%A %B %d, %Y %R')) as interval second(9) to second) as char(10)) as int)  +1262304000)) as interval second(9) to second) as char(10)) as int)
```

notice that I am calculating the length of time from the completiontime to 1-1-2010 then adding 12 billion seconds (going all the way back to the unix epoch is too big for Informix's interval seconds(9) to second, hence the two-steps) so that I can then plug it into the dbinfo("utc_to_datetime") sp to convert it back to a datetime in the right timezone, then subtracting it from sysdate.  The worst part (besides the six casts) is that the completiontimes that I am dealing with are all within 24 hours of sysdate, most are within 10 minutes, yet I am adding on 12 billion seconds so that I can use the only function I can find that converts between timezones.

My question is, Is this really the best way to do this?  By the way, this works very quickly, and my query is back down to a reasonable execution time (<0.5 seconds), I'm just looking at this query and thinking that there has got to be a better way.

Jared

Comment: A simpler way would be either to perform all calculations using UTC or using Unix timestamps (If we ignore time during leap seconds then it is very easy to convert one to another). You don't need local time to calculate the number of seconds since the user completed the task if the completion time is given in UTC and therefore there is no need to worry about DST and UTC offsets. You should be able to get the current time as UTC time or Unix timestamp easily.

Comment: ok, that is my question.  you say, "you should be able to..." and that is what I keep thinking -- "I should be able to..." but I can't find any way to do this.  any way I can find to get the current time returns it in the local timezone.  Is there a way to get the current UTC time or unix timestamp from Informix?  so far I have not been able to find this.

Comment: *"Is there a way to get the current UTC time or unix timestamp from Informix?"* -- looks like a good question (you could ask it separately if there is none yet).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of `sysdate` you can use `DBINFO('utc_current')`:

```
SELECT DBINFO('utc_current') - (completionTime interval seconds(9) to seconds) FROM ...
```